# How can I move a lower div to the top in a colspan Boostrap Layout?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

For mobile I'd like the div NAV to be moved to the very top.

Desktop:

CONTENT | TEASER 
................. | NAV

Mobile:

NAV
CONTENT
TEASER

I've already reversed the layout, i.e. I set it up the way it is supposed to be for mobile (below 992px) and use the push/pull classes to push the NAV div to the bottom right for desktop viewports. Unfortunately so far it doesn't quite work yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8"> NAVI </div>    
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 left" style="padding-bottom: 200px"> CONTENT </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8"> TEASER </div>  
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aws9pv88/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Basically the HTML Markup is already correct.
All we need to do is position the Nav Layer absolute, give it a left and a margin-left, as well as defin a width, and give the Teaser div a margin-bottom.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aws9pv88/9/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 nav"> NAVI </div>    
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4" style="padding-bottom: 200px"> CONTENT </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 teaser"> TEASER </div>
    <div style="clear:left"></div>

    </div>
```

This is a solution made up of bootsrap + absolute positioning.
If however somone find a bootstrap only solution, feel free to post it here.